# Incremental counter Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work out how to make this counter work. After a certain amount of animations have played, I want to make the page refresh. I know my code sucks. I'm not educated in this and I'm very new, not to mention it being difficult to concentrate (to say the least) where I'm staying at the moment... so be nice. Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function loop() {
        var p = 0;
        if (p = 3) {
            location.reload(true);
        } else {
            $("#p3").delay("1000").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#p3").delay("1000").fadeOut("slow", loop);
            p + 1;
        };
        loop();
    });
```

Comment: Try to repro your issue http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I tried to make it work there but I'm doing something wrong, and I don't know what it is. I think the basic principal of the counter is OK but I'm doing something wrong and I don't have the experience to know what it is...

Comment: My point about repro is that it'll help you understand what code you need to include inside your question.  For instance, what element is `#p3`?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I thought that would confuse things. #P3 is just a paragraph that appears at a certain time, it has no relation to the variable P, which is just a counter to refresh the page after three loops of the fadein code. The actual FadeIn, FadeOut code on the page I'm using is much longer, this is a shortened version. There are around ten paragraphs that I'm using in this way on my webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if (p = 3)` statement is using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `===` or `==`. So `p` gets assigned to `3`, the result of which is truthy, so the `else` statement is never executed.

Also your `p` variable is declared inside your `loop()` function, so it gets reset every time the function is called - you could move that declaration to just before the function (keep it inside the document ready handler: no need to make it global).

Also the line `p + 1;` doesn't do anything: it doesn't increment `p` because you'd need to assign the result back to `p` with `p = p + 1`, the shorthand for which is `p += 1` or just `p++`.

Finally, your code as posted has a syntax error: you are missing the closing `}` from the `loop()` function. I would guess the intention is to end the function and then call it, so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var p = 0;  // <--- moved outside function
    function loop() {
        if (p === 3) {   // <-- changed = to ===
            location.reload(true);
        } else {
            $("#p3").delay("1000").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#p3").delay("1000").fadeOut("slow", loop);
            p++; // <-- changed from p + 1
        };
    } // <--- this is the missing bracket
    loop();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write all this out. It's very appreciated. Have an upvote and a correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've made some assumptions and written what I believe is what you want, code is un-tested.:

**Change it to:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var globalP = 0;
     //this is called when fadeOut completes.
    function fadeComplete() {
       if (globalP == 3) {//if it is 3 reload..
            location.reload(true);
        } else {
            globalP++;//increment counter 
            animate();//start animation again...
        }
    }
    function animate() {
       //start fading in...
       $("#p3").delay("1000").fadeIn("slow", function() {
           //start fading out when the fadeIn completes.
            //should this happen? Since you're fading in the SAME element.
          $("#p3").delay("1000").fadeOut("slow", fadeComplete);
       });
    };
    animate();
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking your time to answer this question. I'm going with the above answer just because it's a bit simpler :D but thanks anyway, this would also work!!